# Map claims to custom ApplicationUser's properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to understand how to add a custom ApplicationUser class to my ASP.NET Core MVC application which authenticates to an external system (another MVC project that uses IdentityServer 4).
I have customized the IProfileService in the IdentityServer 4 app to add a custom claim to the user's profile, say "avatarUrl", with an url as the value of the claim.
Now, in my client app I have created the custom ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
}
```

How do I customize the ASP.NET Identity framework so that, after logging in to the external IdSrv, the User in HttpContext has this property exposed (not through a claim)? I want to be able to do this, in a controller method:

```
this.HttpContext.User.Identity.AvatarUrl
```

Do I need to create a class that derives from ClaimsPrincipal? And which method, on which class, do I need to override to assign my CustomClaimsPrincipal to HttpContext?

EDIT:
I tried to inject a custom AppSignInManager, but I noticed it doesn't get used.
Looks like, since the app calls IdentityServer for authentication, with OpenIdConnect, SignInManager doesn't get involved in the process.
In the ConfigureServices I have the standard code for auth with an external Identity Server:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        #region Oidc events
        options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = context =>
        {
            // For debugging
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
        #endregion

        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Authority").Value;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "myapp";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        // TODO: provide a real client secret
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        foreach (var scope in "openid profile email".Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }

        options.ClaimActions.Remove("name");
        options.ClaimActions.Remove("email");
        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
        options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("avatarUrl", "avatarUrl");
    });
```

So now I'm wondering... since SignInManager isn't called, where is the code that creates the ClaimsPrincipal object, after authenticating with Oidc? Which method do I need to override?

Comment: You're confusing different concepts. No matter how your user is stored, accessed, authenticated, etc., the end result is a principal (a basic and generic representation of a "user"). The result of authing via IdentityServer is just going to be a principal with claims attached to it. There is no `ApplicationUser` any more. That only exists over on the IdentityServer side, and even then, only as a means for persisting users to a store. IdentityServer could care less how that part is managed.

Comment: Ok yeah while I was writing the question I noticed I was a bit confused...
Anyway, is the solution to create a custom SignInManager? I seem to understand that it's in its methods for authentication that the ClaimsPrincipal is attached to the HttpContext...

Comment: @Etchelon Did you ever find a solution for this?